# Exception in AES decryption algorithm in java

Tags: java, encryption

I got an exception in the following code for AES algorithm in java.

Code decryptes an encrypted string and returns the original string.

Plz help me to fix this.

Code:

```
public class AES 

{

public byte[] encrypted;

 public byte[] original;

 public String originalString;

public static String asHex (byte buf[]) 

{ 

StringBuffer strbuf = new StringBuffer(buf.length * 2);

 int i; for (i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) 

{

 if (((int) buf[i] & 0xff) < 0x10) strbuf.append("0"); 

strbuf.append(Long.toString((int) buf[i] & 0xff, 16)); 

}

 return strbuf.toString();

 }

 public String AESencryptalgo(byte[] text)

 { 

String newtext=""; 

// Get the KeyGenerator

 try

 {

    KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");

    kgen.init(128); // 192 and 256 bits may not be available

 // Generate the secret key specs. 

SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();

 byte[] raw = skey.getEncoded();

 SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");

 // Instantiate the cipher Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES"); 

cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec); encrypted = cipher.doFinal(text); 

System.out.println("encrypted string: " + asHex(encrypted)); 

cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec); original = cipher.doFinal(encrypted); 

originalString = new String(original); System.out.println("Original string: " + originalString + " " + asHex(original));

 } 

catch(Exception e)

 { } 

finally 

{

 newtext=new String(encrypted);

 System.out.println("ENCRYPTED "+newtext);

//AESdecryptalgo(newtext.getBytes()); 

return newtext;

 }

 } 

public String AESdecryptalgo(byte[] text)

 { 

// Get the KeyGenerator

 try

 {

 KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");

 kgen.init(128); // 192 and 256 bits may not be available 

// Generate the secret key specs. 

SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();

 byte[] raw = skey.getEncoded(); 

SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES"); 

// Instantiate the cipher

 Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES"); 

cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);

 original = cipher.doFinal(text); //Exception occurs here

 originalString = new String(original);

 System.out.println("Original string: " + originalString + " " + asHex(original)); 

}

 catch(Exception e)

 {

 System.out.println("exception"); 

}

 finally

{ 

System.out.println("DECRYPTED "+originalString);

 return originalString;

 } 

} 

public static void main(String[] args)

{

AES a=new AES();

a.AESencryptalgo("hello".getBytes());

System.out.println(); 

}} 
`
```

exception:

```
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded at  
com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE_f.b(DashoA13*..) at
com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE_f.b(DashoA13*..) at
com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(DashoA13*..) at
javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(DashoA13*..)
```

Comment: you should reformat your code

Comment: @ Xavier Combelle I have reformatted

Comment: @user: What *is* the exception? At the very least replace your println with `e.printStackTrace()` and report back.

Comment: @theatrus: Exception is :
Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher

Comment: Stack trace:
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE_f.b(DashoA13*..)
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE_f.b(DashoA13*..)
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(DashoA13*..)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(DashoA13*..)

Answer (score 14):

According to [Java™ Cryptography Architecture (JCA) Reference Guide](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html#trans) (emphasis mine):

> `Cipher` objects are obtained by using
>   one of the [`Cipher getInstance()` static
>   factory methods](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html#ProviderImplReq). Here, the algorithm
>   name is slightly different than with
>   other engine classes, in that it
>   specifies not just an algorithm name,
>   but a "transformation". A
>   transformation is a string that
>   describes the operation (or set of
>   operations) to be performed on the
>   given input to produce some output. A
>   transformation always includes the
>   name of a cryptographic algorithm
>   (e.g., `DES`), and may be followed by a
>   mode and padding scheme.
>
> A transformation is of the form:
>
> - "*algorithm/mode/padding*" or
> - "*algorithm*"
>
> For example, the following are valid transformations:
>
> - `"DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding"`
> - `"DES"`
>
> If just a transformation name is specified, the system will
>   determine if there is an
>   implementation of the requested
>   transformation available in the
>   environment, and if there is more than
>   one, returns there is a preferred one.
>
> If both a transformation name and a
>   package provider are specified, the
>   system will determine if there is an
>   implementation of the requested
>   transformation in the package
>   requested, and throw an exception if
>   there is not.
>
> **If no mode or padding is specified,
>   provider-specific default values for
>   the mode and padding scheme are used.**
>   For example, the `SunJCE` provider uses
>   `ECB` as the default mode, and
>   `PKCS5Padding` as the default padding
>   scheme for `DES`, `DES-EDE` and `Blowfish`
>   ciphers. This means that in the case
>   of the `SunJCE` provider:
>
> ```
> Cipher c1 = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> Cipher c1 = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
> ```
>
> are equivalent statements.
>
> Using modes
>   such as CFB and OFB, block ciphers can
>   encrypt data in units smaller than the
>   cipher's actual block size. When
>   requesting such a mode, you may
>   optionally specify the number of bits
>   to be processed at a time by appending
>   this number to the mode name as shown
>   in the "*DES/CFB8/NoPadding*" and
>   "*DES/OFB32/PKCS5Padding*"
>   transformations. If no such number is
>   specified, a provider-specific default
>   is used. (For example, the `SunJCE`
>   provider uses a default of 64 bits for
>   DES.) Thus, block ciphers can be
>   turned into byte-oriented stream
>   ciphers by using an 8 bit mode such as
>   CFB8 or OFB8.
>
> **[Appendix A](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html#AppA) of this document contains a
>   list of standard names that can be
>   used to specify the algorithm name,
>   mode, and padding scheme components of
>   a transformation.**
>
> The objects returned by factory
>   methods are uninitialized, and must be
>   initialized before they become usable.

Because your code does not specify mode or padding, provider-specific default values are being used. It appears that your provider is `SunJCE` and that it's default padding is probably `"NoPadding"`. With this padding, you are responsible for ensuring that the size of the byte array being encrypted is a multiple of the number of bytes in the secret key. You can make you're life easier by specifying the mode and padding in your transformation:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
```

**WARNING: You should not use ECB mode in real code. Try CBC instead.**

**Update:** I didn't think it was fair to recommend CBC mode without offering a little sample of how it works:

```
public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    byte[] data = "hello".getBytes();

    KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
    keyGenerator.init(128); // 192 and 256 bits may not be available

    SecretKey secretKey = keyGenerator.generateKey();

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

    // By initializing the cipher in CBC mode, an "initialization vector" has been randomly
    // generated. This initialization vector will be necessary to decrypt the encrypted data.
    // It is safe to store the initialization vector in plain text for later use. You can obtain
    // it's bytes by calling iv.getIV().
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
    IvParameterSpec iv = cipher.getParameters().getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class);
    byte[] encryptedData = cipher.doFinal(data);

    // When decrypting the encrypted data, you must provide the initialization vector used
    // during the encryption phase.
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, iv);
    byte[] decryptedData = cipher.doFinal(encryptedData);

    if (!Arrays.equals(data, decryptedData)) {
        throw new Exception("Data was not decrypted successfully");
    }
}
```

Comment: No, I am gtting IILegal block size exception.
The new version of the code is at....
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181535/exception-in-aes-decryption-algorithm-in-java

Answer (score 0):

Well if this is the error Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher. Than the answear is obvious, the length of your buffer must be a multiple of 16. 
Have you checked the length of buf[]?

Answer (score 0):

Your code manages to get almost everything wrong. Just for a start, your mistakes include:

1. generating a new random symmetric key before encryption and decryption. You have to use the same key to decrypt that was used to encrypt.
2. Using String as a container for binary data. cipher output is cannot be reliably made into a String unless you use an encoding, such as base64.
3. Your exception handling is incorrect.

Furthermore, your code runs without exceptions for me.