# Null PointerException in AES algorithm

Tags: java

This is the code for encrypting and decrypting a string in java using AES algorithm.

StackTrace:

```
    javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE_f.b(DashoA13*..)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE_f.b(DashoA13*..)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(DashoA13*..)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(DashoA13*..)
    at test.AES.AESdecryptalgo(AES.java:76)
    at test.AES.main(AES.java:95)
```

Code:

```
package test;
import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.*;
import java.security.*;

public class AES
{
  public byte[] encrypted;
  public byte[] original;

  public String originalString;
  Cipher cipher;
  SecretKeySpec skeySpec;
  IvParameterSpec spec;
  byte [] iv;
  /*public static String asHex (byte buf[])
  {
    StringBuffer strbuf = new StringBuffer(buf.length * 2);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
    if (((int) buf[i] & 0xff) < 0x10)
    strbuf.append("0");
    strbuf.append(Long.toString((int) buf[i] & 0xff, 16));
  }
  return strbuf.toString();
}*/
  public AES()
  {
        try
        {
            KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
            kgen.init(128);
            SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();
            byte[] raw = skey.getEncoded();
            skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {ex.printStackTrace();}
  }
public String AESencryptalgo(byte[] text)
{
    String newtext="";
    try
    {
        // byte[] raw = skey.getEncoded();
        //SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
            AlgorithmParameters param = cipher.getParameters();
            IvParameterSpec ivspec=param.getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class);
            iv=ivspec.getIV();
            spec=new IvParameterSpec(iv);
        //AlgorithmParameters params = cipher.getParameters();
        //iv = params.getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class).getIV();
        encrypted = cipher.doFinal(text);

    }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   finally
   {
      newtext=new String(encrypted);
       //System.out.println("ENCRYPTED "+newtext);
       return newtext;
    }
}
public  String AESdecryptalgo(byte[] text)
{
    try
    {

        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec,spec);
        original = cipher.doFinal(text);   //Exception occurs here
        originalString = new String(original);

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {

        return originalString;
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    AES a=new AES();
    String encrypt=a.AESencryptalgo("hello".getBytes());
    System.out.println(encrypt);
    String decrypt=a.AESdecryptalgo(encrypt.getBytes());
    System.out.println(decrypt);
}
```

}`

Comment: Can you please include the exception stack trace?

Comment: Possible duplicates (by same user): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180878/exception-in-aes-decryption-algorithm-in-java, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181535/exception-in-aes-decryption-algorithm-in-java

Comment: I made the modifications suggested in my prev posts and i got different exceptions.

Comment: Except you didn't bother to try to understand the other posts. StackOverflow isn't WriteMyCodeForMe.com nor ICanNotBeBotheredToLearnWhatIamDoing.com

Comment: Your stacktrace no longer seems to match your code.  Line 48 of what you've posted couldn't possibly throw an NPE. Please update the stack trace or the code so that they match!

Comment: Testing You Values here.....

http://www.hanewin.net/encrypt/aes/aes-test.htm

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your constructor isn't really a constructor, so `skey`, `cipher` and the other private members are never initialized.

Constructors are defined without return types, so you need to change `public void AES()` to `public AES`.

---

Okay, apparently you fixed that problem.  The next is that `cipher.init` doesn't take a `SecretKey`, it takes a `SecretKeySpec`.  Working from [this example I found](http://www.coderanch.com/t/444666/Security/AES-Encryption) you need something like:

```
byte[] raw = skey.getEncoded();
SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
```

...and then you can pass `skeySpec` where you're currently passing `skey` to `cipher.init`.

---

Onwards, I suppose, unless I'm counting wrong your issue is with this line:

```
 iv = cipher.getParameters().getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class).getIV();
```

If you verify that `cipher` is not null, the places on this line that could throw a `NullPointerException` are after the `getParameters()` call or after the `getParameterSpec()` call.  You can easily determine which of these calls is causing the exception to be thrown by splitting this into multiple lines and examining the stack trace (*you* should look at the stack trace and determine where the exception is actually being thrown).

If I had to bet on it I'd guess that `cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");` isn't valid. I suspect this would work okay if you had

```
cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
```

Comment: But if I am using Cipher.getInstance("AES") then it will throw Bad Padding Exception.
I changed it ot CSB mode as suggested by a user in my prev post.

Comment: @user372066 have you determined where the NPE is actually occurring?

Comment: Its occurring at
IvParameterSpec ivspec=param.getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class);

Comment: @user, then `param` is null, which means `cipher.getParameters()` is returning null.

Comment: I have solved null pointer exception
Now Ia m getting IIlegalBlockSize Exception

Comment: @sparkle: and so we have to guess where you are getting the IllegalBlockSize exception? This game isn't very fun. I'm thinking of a number between 1 and a million; what is it?

Comment: For anyone wondering, the NullPointerException on getParameters() is caused by an Android 4.3.x bug: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58191